# Как сделать исключение повторного запуска программы в Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Предположим, я нажал на ярлык программы, программа запустилась, второй раз нажимаю на ярлык и выдается сообщение, что программа уже запущена или если программа свернута, она при этом разворачивается и становится видимой на переднем плане, если запущено много окон?

Answer (score 4):

Я обычно делаю так:

```
implementation
var g_hAppMutex: THandle;

{$R *.dfm}

function OneInstance: boolean;
var g_hAppCritSecMutex: THandle;
    dw: Longint;
begin
     g_hAppCritSecMutex := CreateMutex( nil, true, PChar(Application.Title + '.OneInstance32.CriticalSection') );
     g_hAppMutex := CreateMutex( nil, false, PChar(Application.Title + 'OneInstance32.Default') );
     dw := WaitForSingleObject( g_hAppMutex, 0 );
     Result :=  (dw <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
     ReleaseMutex( g_hAppCritSecMutex );
     CloseHandle( g_hAppCritSecMutex );
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not OneInstance then
    begin
      MessageBoxEx(Application.Handle, PChar('Приложение уже открыто! Запуск второго экземпляра запрещен.'), PChar('...'), MB_ICONSTOP + MB_OK, $0419);
      Application.Terminate;
    end
end;
```

...

```
initialization

    g_hAppMutex := 0;

    finalization

    if LongBool( g_hAppMutex ) then
       begin
            ReleaseMutex( g_hAppMutex);
            CloseHandle( g_hAppMutex );
       end;

    end.
```

Comment: Ваша реализация не разворачивает исходное окно, если то, например, свернуто.

Comment: А можно по порядку, что за чем и для чего? На дельфях не кодил уже пару лет, может, чего изменилось, а, может, я что-то не понимал ранее, но всегда использовал для запрета (без разворачивания окна) основной модуль и простенькую процедуру в нем.

Comment: Собственно код (упрощенная версия, без дополнительных проверок):
    
procedure canStart;
    var
        Mtx: THandle;
    begin
        Mtx := CreateMutex(nil, false, 'program_start_mutex');
        if WaitForSingleObject(Mtx, 0) <> WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
            begin
                MessageDlg('Нельзя!', mtError, [mbOk], 0);
                Application.Terminate;
            end;  
    end;

    begin
        canStart;
        Application.Title := 'My Program...';
        //...
    end.

Comment: Работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Dex у меня Ваша процедура почему-то не работает, можно поподробней, как использовать, что куда?

Comment: @Андрющенко Андрей, "почему-то не работает" это такое сообщение компилятора?

Answer (score 1):

Простой запрет повторного запуска - *задача тривиальная.* В код запуска программы нужно добавить проверку на то, что программа с таким же **путем запуска** `ехе-файла` в данный момент не работает. *Если такая же программа уже есть, то просто выходим.*

Реализовать же разворот уже имеющегося окна тоже можно двумя способами - искать нужный `HWND` и отправлять ему сообщение о том, чтобы он развернулся, или же поступить как сделано [**здесь.**](http://sheepdogguides.com/dt4l.htm)

**Отмечу, что в методе по ссылке для одного запуска используется глобальный мьютекс, что тоже является вариантом решения первой подзадачи.**

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуй, один из самых простых, но, скорее всего не самый надёжный способ: использовать WinAPI. Есть такая функция FindWindow - принимает 2 параметра: первый - имя класса главного окна, второй - заголовок окна; сама функция возвращает 0, если такого окна нет, и дескриптор в противном случае. Код нужно писать в исходнике программы. Пример:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  Windows, // Этот модуль должен быть подключен!
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

Var
  hWind: HWND;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
{Если имя класса главной формы не TForm1, то его следует изменить, то же самое с заголовком окна.}
  hWind:=FindWindow('TForm1', 'Form1');

{Можно использовать такой вариант записи функции, если есть вероятность, что заголовок окна изменится в результате работы приложения.}

hWind:=FindWindow('TForm1', Nil);

If (hWind<>0) Then
    Begin
      SetForegroundWindow(hWind); // выводит окно на первый план
      Application.Terminate; // завершает повторно запущенное приложение
    End;

Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов несколько, но самый оптимальный - смотрите запущенные задачи, и если находите еще одну такую же, то посылаете ей сообщение развернуться, а себя убиваете. Это упрощенно, а реальный код получится весьма объемный.

Comment: А чем он оптимальнее того же Mutex"а?